# Spacing between image and text in text message (iOS 9)

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app lets the user send an image in a text message as well as a pre-written text, when an action is called.

The problem is that there is a blank line between the image and the text, in the dialog box. It's a problem because when the user sends the text, the image is in a seperate speech bubble, and the blank line remains in the text's speech bubble:

[image]

How can I fix this?

My code:

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])

{
[controller setRecipients:nil];
[controller setBody:@"Text."];

NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 1);
[controller addAttachmentData:data typeIdentifier:@"image/jpeg" filename:@"Image.jpeg"];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL]; }
```

Thank you!

EDIT: This problem is only for iOS 9. I tried the app on an iOS 8,4 device, and the blank line was not there.